# ASP.NET & Google Maps API Error Code "620"on shared hosting

Tags: google-maps, shared-hosting

We have a Map It feature on a Real Estate Website and its on a Shared Host, the feature basically shows you the location of a property of works fine for a few hours a day but it stops working later in the day because of error Code "620" for the map request from Google maps API KEY.

we need this issue fix immediately.

Sample could be found here http://www.luxuryrentalsmiamibeach.com/The-Setai-Miami-Beach-13

click on the Map It link to see example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Map It" link works flawlessly ATM. The Google error Code 620 means `G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES` which either means you had too many API requests per IP per day or in an unspecified time frame.

About the too many API requests per day you cannot do much besides load balancing, changing your IP or paying for the Google Maps API. About the too many API requests per time frame (e.g. 2000 requests per minute) you can do something by delaying your requests.
Also think about caching your results serverside to not put too much strain on the Google servers.

There are several tutorials available on the 620 error and how to circumvent it, just [google for it](http://www.google.com/search?q=google+maps+api+620). To get you started you can read "[Geocoding multiple addresses](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/geomulti.htm)"